# Given PSD rank one matrix $V = vv^T$, how to find $v$ efficiently?

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition

Suppose I have a rank one positive semidefinite matrix $V = vv^T$, how to find $v$ efficiently?

$v\in\mathbb{R}^n$

I know the diagonal term $v_1^2, \ldots,v_n^2$ will tell me something; however, we have to choose $\pm$ sign.  Also we can consider other terms to help us; however, if $n$ is large, how to find $v$ efficiently?  (particularly when writing it in a code.)

Comment: Every row and every column of $V$ is a rescaled copy of $v$, and to find the scale factor you just need to look at the first nonzero diagonal entry.

Comment: $\pm$ sign is not possible to decide as $vv^T=(-v)(-v)^T$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan what do you mean after "and"? this scale factor can be positive or negative

Comment: Yeah, but you can only recover $v$ up to a global sign anyway, as A.G. points out.

Comment: But you can, of course, find out the relative signs via $v_iv_j$.